# returning the element in one list based on the index and maximum value of an element in another list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of lists which I converted into a numpy array:

```
lsts = ([[1,2,3], ['a','b','a']],
        [[4,5,6,7], ['a','a','b','b']], 
        [[1,2,3],['b','a','b']])

np_lsts = np.array(lsts)
```

I want to return the largest element in the first list where a 'b' occurs in the second list. I think I have to use indexes but am stuck!

i.e. I want to return (2, 7, 3) in this case

Answer (score 1):

That will do:

```
[max(u for u,v in zip(x,y) if v=='b') for x,y in lsts if 'b' in y]
```

Using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#max) in a nested  list comprehension

Comment: This fails if the second list does not contain a 'b'. e.g.: `lsts=([[1,2,3], ['a','c','e']])`

Comment: @CraigBurgler I edited the answer and fixed that issue

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to your problem:

```
lsts = ([[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'a']],
        [[4, 5, 6, 7], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']],
        [[1, 2, 3], ['b', 'a', 'b']],
        [[1, 2, 3], ['a']]
        )

result = []
for l in lsts:
    indices = [l[0][index] for index, v in enumerate(l[1]) if v == 'b']
    if indices:
        result.append(max(indices))

print result
```

Comment: if the second list does not contain a 'b', the code attempts to append `max([])` which generates a syntax error

Comment: @CraigBurgler Nice catch! I've edited the code to make it work in that case ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following function returns a `result` list. If needed, you could return a tuple instead of a list.

```
def maxNum(lsts, character):
    result = []
    for entry in lsts:
        if character in entry[1]:
            result.append(max(entry[0]))
    return result

# lsts = ... # (put lsts here)

print maxNum(lsts, 'b')
```

Comment: This returns [3,7,3] for the OP example.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_max(l):
    first = True
    for e1, e2 in zip(l[0], l[1]):
        if e2 == 'b' and first:
            max = e1
            first = False
        elif e2 == 'b' and e1 > max:
            max = e1
    return max

result = ()
for l in lsts:
    if 'b' in l[1]:
        result += (get_max(l),)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a lot more efficient than the current solutions if the sublists have a lot of elements, since it is vectorized over those sublists:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
results = [npi.group_by(k).max(v) for v,k in lsts]
```